# "Not enough free disk space" dialog showed on Software Updater

Tags: software-installation, updates

Whenever I try to update the software using Software Updater, I get this dialog:

[image: dialog showing the warning message]

which prevents me from getting the upgrade - and going through `apt-get upgrade` results in partially upgraded sotware. Also, I've done the cleaning suggested in the last sentence. It still shows up.

The only left thing to try is dealing with `/boot`, but I do not know what can be deleted and what has to be untouched.

[image]

Which is the best, "elementary-backed" solution to the problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot

There are several solutions to your problem listed in this thread from askubuntu

Comment: Thank you! It worked well. Can I ask you to post it as an answer? I want it to be visible as "answered" for people who are having this problem...and I want to reward your answer, of course.

Comment: I dont think links are accepted as an answere. So I'll leave it to someone willing to do the work to gather that karma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to safely free space in the `/boot` folder that works for every derivative of Ubuntu is the following:

1. Open the Terminal application and type `uname -r` to get the current version of the kernel used by your system.
2. Get a list of all the installed kernel by typing

`dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-" | grep -e '[0-9]'`

*For ones who'd like to know how that works*. There's a similar answer [on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/259092/270523) from which I've taken the information; kudos to [Kultom](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/320/kultom), who linked it in a comment.

3. Once you've checked that your current version of the kernel doesn't appear in the list, merge the previous command with `sudo apt-get -y purge` to remove all the old kernels. Thus, you will finally have to type

`dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-" | grep -e '[0-9]' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge`

It worked well for me and many users gave positive feedback on this procedure. It is not strictly "elementary-backed", but it works.